# plotting a graph using R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a bar graph between shapes and mean of complete of the following data table using R
Now my question is how can I plot a bar graph.I tried this but it doesn't work

```
    (shp <- tibble(Type   = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),  shapes    = c("square", "rectangle", "rectangle", "square"),  in_num = c(500, 800, 900, 1200),  complete = c(4, 9, 3, 8)
))
    shp %>% group_by(shapes) %>% summarise(Avg = mean(complete))
    ggplot(data = shp, mapping = aes(x = shapes, y = Avg)) +geom_bar()
```

Comment: Which bit doesn't work? Do you get an error message or a blank plot or does your computer catch fire?

Comment: It seems like you're missing a closing bracket after `mean(complete)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I forgot to close the bracket while copying the data here.

Comment: Below is the error it shows while plotting. ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): object 'Avg' not found

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     rpr <- mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `stat = "identity"` to your `geom_bar()`. And put the closing parentheses after the `summarise` command.

```
 shp %>% 
  group_by(shapes) %>% 
  summarise(Avg = mean(complete)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = shapes, y = Avg, fill = shapes)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = F) +
  theme_bw()
```